# Karate Netty - CallSingle but not so single

Tags: karate

What I had till today:

I have `get_jwt.feature` and I call it as a part of `karate-config.js`. Since I have used one account `test@test.com` I needed only one jwt and I can reuse it across scenarios. `callSingle` worked as a charm in this case.

Today:

Suddenly I have need for jwt's from two accounts which I dont want to generate for each scenario, `callSingle` falls short of this task as it does exactly what its supposed to be doing. Now I have hacky idea, I can simply make two files, `get_jwt.feature` and `get_jwt_user2.feature`, and single call them each.

So my question: Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "2 levels" of calls. So point the `callSingle()` to a JS function that calls `get_jwt.feature` 2 times, maybe with different arguments and then return a JSON. Pseudo-code below. First is `get_jwts.js`:

```
function fn(users) {
  var jwt1 = karate.call('get_jwt.feature', users.user1);
  var jwt2 = karate.call('get_jwt.feature', users.user2);
  return { jwt1: jwt1, jwt2: jwt2 };
};
```

Then in `karate-config.js`

```
config.jwts = karate.callSingle('classpath:get_jwts.js', users);
```

And now you should be able to do this:

```
* print jwts.jwt1
* print jwts.jwt2
```

You can also do a feature-->feature call chain. Do let me know if this works !

EDIT: see Babu's answer in the comments, looks like you can pass an array to `callSingle()` ! so that may be quite convenient :)

Comment: feature call like `var users = [{"userName": "A","Password": "AP"}, {"userName": "B","Password": "BP"}];`  `var tokenResponses = karate.callSingle("get_jwt.feature",users);` would also work right ?

Comment: @BabuSekaran no I mean that in the example I provided the callSingle is to a JS which then calls 2 features. I am saying that callSingle can call a feature also (which in turn can call 2 features and return the "aggregated" variables

Comment: @BabuSekaran and `callSingle()` does NOT loop over arrays ! does it ?

Comment: @BabuSekaran O M G it does loop over arrays - if the call is to a feature :) heh I forgot >_<

Comment: way @BabuSekaran suggested is not working for me, it would say variables are missing.
i have:
`var users = [{ baseUrl: config['baseUrl'], email: config['iam_root_email'], password: config['password'] }, { baseUrl: config['baseUrl'], email: config['iam_child_email'], password: config['password'] }]` and its saying `baseUrl` is missing

Comment: can't say for sure without seeing your whole setup: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: for sure, will submit a issue later on today, ty